# replace or remove multiple xml tags from parsed string

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am using jquery parseXML to parse xml text input by user. Before parsing, I have requirement to replace/remove certain tags. I am using regExp to replace these, under a common replace function. But I ended up writing too many replace actions. Is there a way to combine or optimize this function? here's my function:

```
function replaceInlineElements(str){
  str = str.replace(/<strong>/g, '(strong)');
  str = str.replace(/<\/strong>/g, '(/strong)');
  str = str.replace(/\\n/g, '');
  str = str.replace(/<code>/g, '(code)');
  str = str.replace(/<\/code>/g, '(/code)');
  str = str.replace(/<ac:rich-text-body>/g, '');
  str = str.replace(/<\/ac:rich-text-body>/g, '');
  str = str.replace(/ac:/g, '');
  return str;
}
```

Comment: Questions about optimizing working code are better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @charlietfl : Thanks for the tip. I wasn't aware of that one. I will look into it.